# Countdown to certain date and adding x hours

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Timer Main

```
    $curDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-8 hours"));

    $timecountdownend = strtotime($curDate) + strtotime("+1 hours");
    $timecountdownstart = strtotime("-8 hour");
    $timeleft = $timecountdownend - $timecountdownstart;

    if (isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type'] == "timerupdate") {
        echo $timeleft;
    }
?>
```

Timer Update 5 Seconds

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var timerText = $("[timer]");

    setInterval(function(){
        $.post("timer.php", {type: "timerupdate"}, function(data){
            timerText.html("Time Left:" + data + " seconds timer.")
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

---

***WHAT ARE YOU TRYING TO ACHIEVE?***

The idea is when a user reserves an item, expiration date is set into the database so that the USER that reserved the item cannot hold it forever. So for example:

> User A: Reserve Item A.
>   [SERVER] $database->insert("reservation", $curDate);
>   [SERVER] 2016-04-03 16:00:00 (After 30 minutes this item is expired)

That what's supposed to happen in the back-end.

***WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED?***

I've done tons of googling to see how I could add x hours or minutes to the current date and pass that on to become a unix timestamp.

***WHAT IS YOUR PROBLEM?***
Whenever I try the code above it works but doesn't come up with the right output I need. Specifically the problem is at `$timecountdownend = strtotime($curDate) + strtotime("+1 hours");`

** NEW **

```
date_default_timezone_get("America/New York");

$curDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-8 hours"));
$date = new DateTime($curDate);
date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('2 hour'));

$timecountdownend = strtotime($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$timecountdownstart = strtotime("-8 hour");
$timeleft = $timecountdownend - $timecountdownstart;

if (isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type'] == "timerupdate") {
    echo $timeleft;
}
```

OUTPUT: 7200 seconds (STUCK though). It's precise but it's not counting down.

Comment: did you consider [http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) ?

Comment: @Braza Nope I have not. I'll give it a shot right now and tell you what happens,

Comment: just look down the page, examples are pretty good test :)

Comment: the only tricky part is to understand how this syntax work : `$date->add(new DateInterval('P7Y5M4DT4H3M2S'));` P7 means add 7 years H3 means add 3 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php ?

the only tricky part is to understand how this syntax work : `$date->add(new DateInterval('P7Y5M4DT4H3M2S'));` P7 means add 7 years H3 means add 3 hours

Once you save or update the date in your database, send a copy along with the response and in your final response document put this :

https://jsfiddle.net/o740okn4/5/

You will need to make these calls from CDN or get the scripts from git

```
moment.min.js
moment-duration-format.min.js
```

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js
and 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js

Comment: I edited my post but I still get a frozen timer. My time is a lot more precise now though. But it's not counting down to the date.

Comment: Besides, for the client side, you should not communicate a synch date with server, so you can drop ajax call, just get the date of reservation, set it into a Momen.js and put an interval shown as human readable time, I'll prepare a JSfiddle and add it to solution

Comment: and there you go [https://jsfiddle.net/o740okn4/5/](https://jsfiddle.net/o740okn4/5/), I also updated answer :)

Comment: Alright let me test this on xampp and set this up. Just in case I run into trouble or isn't the thing I'm looking for. Because I feel like it's missing something.

Comment: Keep in mind that you need reverse time count so just inverse the calculation, meaning instead of (later - now) do ( now - later) and you will get a readable human countdown time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108112/discussion-between-repeatercreeper-and-braza).